# VSCode clear errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, world-of-warcraft

I am self teaching myself Lua by building a WoW addon; I have no background in coding at all.

After Notepad++ broke all extensions I changed to VSCode and I find it great and very flexible.

I have two questions about VSCode functionality.

1. I currently have an extreme amount of errors showing in my Problems page and I wish to clear all the errors but I have not been able to find a way to this.
2. A majority of errors are "accessing undefined variable" when it identifies api calls. Is there a way to I can ensure that api calls are not incorrectly identified as an error?
   [image]

Comment: What extension to VS Code do you use? In most of them you need to specify external (from game engine) variables/functions that you may use in this project.

Comment: I use [WoW Bundle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Septh.wow-bundle).
I note that this extension has not been updated since Oct 2018, and the owner has said that they do not intend to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors/warnings are raised by luacheck, a Lua [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

The solution is an appropriate mix of writing proper code and configuring luacheck to not raise unwanted warnings.

Read the [luacheck manual](https://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to find out how to configure luacheck.

Maybe the VS Code extension provides settings for luacheck.

You can use a configuration file, inline configuration comments or command line options to change the behaviour of luacheck.

You'll probably find a luacheck configuration for the WoW API online.

To get rid of the unused loop variable warning you could simply use `_` as variable name. This is commonly used for unused, but necessary values and hence ignored by luacheck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Like mentioned, you can configure Luacheck with the `.luacheckrc` file, see [documentation](https://luacheck.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html). (the ignore patterns here are not recommended and only serve as an example)

```lua
std = "lua51"
ignore = {
    "211", -- unused local variable / function
    "212/self", -- unused argument self
}
globals = {
    "ClearCursor",
    "format",
    "tinsert",
    "unpack",
}
```

2. There's a list of global API [here](https://github.com/Ketho/BlizzardInterfaceResources/blob/live/Resources/GlobalAPI.lua) but it's better to manually add globals to your .luacheckrc instead